# Javascript strptime() is adding one month extra

Tags: javascript, java, strptime, graalvm

From an Spring boot project we are calling GraalVM for processing some rules written in JavaScript. The GraalVM version is 'org.graalvm.sdk=1.0.0-rc11'. When we are using `strptime()`, it's adding one month extra. Like for the date 24/02/2021, it is converted to 24/03/2021. Can you please let me know why this is happening?

Here source is passed as the source date like 24/02/2021

`const return_date = new Date().strptime(source, format(source)).toIsoString()`

NOTE: This is happening if we execute this on the last day of a month like on 31st January, other day it is giving me the expected date returned. So any idea why `strptime()` is behaving like this?

Comment: Is source an java.util.date.Date? If yes, then it comes from the fact that Date's months goes from 0 to 11. Try using LocalData instead https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html

Comment: it is not java.util.date.Date. This is just taken from json, inside javascript function like JSON.parse(source[0].CREATION_DATE). This javascript is executed by GraalVM.

Comment: But JavaScript Date months are also in the range of 0 to 11. 

Comment: I have added a NOTE, about when actually it is happening. This is happening when we are executing on the last day on a month. Other day it is giving correct date. Any idea?

Comment: There is no strptime method in javascript though?

Comment: Your NOTE does not match with the date you have mentioned in the problem. You have mentioned `24/02/2021` in the problem but in the NOTE, you have mentioned *This is happening if we execute this on the last day of a month like on 31st January...*. Make sure you review your question well before hitting the **Submit** button.

Comment: Last day of a month like on 31st January -- this is date when we execute. 
where as ' 24/02/2021' is date of data .. this date is converted to ' 24/03/2021' after processing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

other than strptime() function, You can directly use this way:

*const return_date = new Date(source).toISOString()*